# SharePoint 2010 and 32-bit Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have a scenario where I have 2 servers. One is a 64-bit server to run SharePoint 2010 (front end and backend) and the other is a 32-bit SBS2003 server.

I am wanting to upgrade WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Foundation 2010 on the SharePoint server (which is fine as that one is a 64-bit server) but I was wondering if the fact that the SBS2003 server which has Active Directory on it will cause me problem as that is 32-bit.

Does anyone know if this will be ok or if I will need to upgrade my Active Directory server and operating system to a 64-bit version?

Cheers

Comment: Active Directory has no concept of bitness.

Comment: @lippie - so do you think SharePoint 2010 (which has to be 64-bit) will connect ok to an SBS2003 Server and use the Active Directory as needed?

Comment: Why not? It would be silly to make AD bit dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their is no requirement for upgrading AD feel free and go for upgrade your wss 3.0 you would not face in any problem due to AD